# How to get Specs for all systems on a network?

Tags: networking, specifications

I have started working in a network of 50+ Computers, most of them vary in terms of specs, some have 64gb of Ram other have 24gb, some have nvidia gpus others have Raedons, Parts are swapped and changed between machine regularly enough, every month or so three - four parts could have moved.

The method I'm currently using is just a locally hosted website, which people can access from 192.x.x.x\StockStatus

I have installed Speccy on all machines and have a list compiled of each machine including specs, with day to day maintenance and troubleshooting along with projects sometimes it can be though to maintain the list, sometimes after swapping parts i'm dragged straight away to resolve another issue, usually daisy chaining throughout the day and I've forgotten to update the list.

I'm wondering are there any business solutions in terms of stock taking over a network, basically a tool i can run once a month which will update all the machine specs in my list.

Are there any better solutions to this, also paying money isn't a viable option unfortunately.

Something Like Speccy where it provides all the hardware / system specs.

Speccy - http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/speccy.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use [OSC Ng](http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/) software - this is a great tool for maintaing a database of equipment. It's opensource, and is operating through software agents installed on end-user machines and servers. Basically, the agent approach is general when considering such software.